# Where is definied the theme location for the main menu in a WordPress template?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am pretty new in WordPress (I came from Joomla) and I have the following doubt related the **Theme Location** of the main menu.

For example, using the preinstalled **Twenty Twelve** theme, if in the backend I go into: **Appearance ---> Menus ---> Manage Location** I can assign my **main-menu** only to a specific **theme location** named **Primary Menu**.

I think that this area is into the **header.php** file of the **Twenty Twelve** theme (because my main menu is shown in the page header) but I can't find it, this is the **header.php** content:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header template for our theme
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="main">
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7) | !(IE 8)  ]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
<?php // Loads HTML5 JavaScript file to add support for HTML5 elements in older IE versions. ?>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </hgroup>

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <h3 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h3>
            <a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></a>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

        <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="main" class="wrapper">
```

Where is this **Primary Menu** or how is it definied in the theme?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is defined in the **functions.php** file with the `register_nav_menu` function:

`register_nav_menu( 'primary', __( 'Primary Menu', 'twentytwelve' ) );`

And then called in the **header.php** file with the `wp_nav_menu` function:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu